# I am working on a C++ program for my grandmother's birthday, however I keep getting error code: error C2451

Tags: c++

I have only taken one C++ class and am planning on filling my grandma's children's names with different stuff, what I have currently is just filler. However when I try to debug myself by changing string type to integer like it tells me to I then just get new error codes. Here is what I have currently, the program is quite simple:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;
string name;

string main() {
    bool done = false;
    while (!done) {

    cout << "Enter one of your children's names, or press 'q' to quit" << endl;
    cin >> name;

    if (name = "q") {
        done = true;
        break;
    }
    else if (name = "Jason") {
        cout << "Jason is your eldest son" << endl;
    }
    else if (name = "Aaron") {
        cout << "Aaron was your second child" << endl;
    }
    else if (name = "Mandy") {
        cout << "Mandy is your only girl" << endl;
    }
    else if (name = "Adam") {
        cout << "Adam came after Mandy" << endl;
    }
    else if (name = "Ben") {
        cout << "Ben is your youngest" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "That name does not exist for your children: try Jason, Aaron, Mandy, Adam, or Ben instead" << endl;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: it should be `int main()`; also, compare operator is `==`, NOT `=`

Comment: When I change it to int main() I then get the error code: C2451: conditional expression of type 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>' is illegal

Comment: I've amended my comment above

Comment: Sometimes doing the right thing exposes other errors.

Answer (score 2):

On your `if and else if` statement you need to change `==` instead of `=` (assignment) in order to check if the values of two operands are equal or not.
Also, in your `String main()` I would recommend to change it for just: `int main()`

Answer (score 1):

Just to reiterate what everyone else has mentioned

- Adjust your if/else compare operator ---> if (name **==** "q")
- Use **int main()**

---

```
    int main()
    {
         bool done = false;
         string name;

         while (!done)
         {
              if (name == "q")
              {
                   done = true;
                   break;
              }
         // Remainder of code goes here

         } // Close while loop
    } // Close main()
```

Comment: `return 0;` is implicit in `main()`.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz:  I'm still a student, so I appreciate your guidance.  I've been following a standard as directed by my professors and didn't realize that I could leave out the return in main()